# Acceder a un objeto de una lista y cambiar su atributo

Tags: java

Muy buenas a todos.
bueno les cuento tengo una lista en mi main esa lista tiene objetos de otra clase y lo que quiero hacer es recorrer la lista y acceder al atributo de un objeto y cambiar su valor

```
RadioReloj radioReloj = new RadioReloj("Azul", 1.0, true, reloj); // este es el objeto

for(int i=0; i<lista.size(); i ++){ // aqui recorro la lista y me devuelve los objetos 
    lista.get(i);                   
        
    }
```

como puedo acceder al atributo azul y cambiarlo por otro ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infiero que **lista** tiene objetos de instancias de **RadioReloj** ya que no veo donde se declara e inicializa lista. Lo que planteas del `for` es correcto, recorres tu lista y ahora por cada objeto en la lista vas a tener que acceder a la propiedad que marcas como **Azul**. Para ello tengo que volver a suponer que **Azul** es el atributo de **RadioReloj** y se llama **color**, por lo que **RadioReloj** va a tener `getColor()` y `setColor(String color)`. Dicho esto para acceder a cada elemento de la lista usas `lista.get(i)` y ahora para cambiarle el valor basta con `lista.get(i).setColor("este es el nuevo valor")`.

Por lo general vas a querer cambiarle el valor en caso de que se cumpla algo, en esos casos vas a tener que usar un `if` y preguntar por dicho valor con `lista.get(i).getColor()`. Por ejemplo: si color es *Azul* lo pasamos a *Verde*

```javascript
for(int i=0; i<lista.size(); i ++){ 
    if("Azul".equals(lista.get(i).getColor())){ //equals compara dos cadenas de string
        lista.get(i).setColor("Verde"); // cambio de color
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

me respondo a mi mismo la respuesta era mas facil de lo que pensaba.

```
    for(int i=0; i<lista.size(); i ++){
        lista.get(i).setColor("Verde");
        
    }
```

de esta forma accedí al atributo azul y lo cambie a verde aun no entiendo muy bien por que, se supone que con `lista.get(i)` accedo al primer elemento no al primer atributo pero luego entiendo como la arraylist la cree de esta forma `ArrayList<RadioReloj> lista = new ArrayList<>();` me permite acceder a los getters y setters de la clase RadioReloj.

Comment: En realidad `lista.get(i)` te devuelve el RadioReloj que está en la posición `i` de la lista, por esa razón puedes acceder a sus getters y setters. Para que lo veas más claro puedes expresarlo de esta manera: `RadioReloj rr = lista.get(i); rr.setColor("Verde");`. No lo cambies, es solo para que lo veas mejor, la manera en que lo pusiste está perfecto.